# How to sort products by price if some products have a discount price (mongoose)?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose

So I'd like to order products by price - ASC and DESC, but some of the products will have a discounted:true attribute. If discounted is true sort should use discountPrice field and if fals - they should use price field.

Im using mongoose version: ^5.1.0

Here is my (not working) solution

```
products.find({}, {sort: { price: 1, discountPrice: 1 }})
```

Using those products:

```
{ 
 name: 'p1',
 price: 10,
 discountPrice: 5,
 discounted: true
},
{ 
 name: 'p2',
 price: 11,
 discountPrice: 8,
 discounted: false
},
{ 
 name: 'p3',
 price: 990,
 discountPrice: 6, 
 discounted: true
}
```

I expect the output to be:
`[p1, p3, p2]`
but the actual output is:
`[p1, p2, p3]`

Comment: You need `aggregate()` for calculations. i.e `.aggregate([{ "$addFields": { "sortOrder": { "$subtract": [ "$price", "$discountPrice" ] } }},{ "$sort": { "discountPrice": 1 } }])` if you wanted the "difference". Your expected order though appears just to be on the "discountPrice" only so `.find({}).sort({ "discountPrice": 1 })`

Comment: If you did mean a calculation and wanted to include the `discounted` field in the logic, then something like `.aggregate([{ "$addFields": { "sortOrder": { "$cond": { 
 "if": "$discounted", "then": { "$subtract": [ "$price", "$discountPrice" ] }, "else": "$price" } } }},{ "$sort": { "discountPrice": 1 } }])` which alternates values base on `true/false` in the field.